# create table using weex

Tags: css, html-table, weex

I need to build an app that has a table. I tried using html `<table>` tags to build a table. Even though it shows the table as i require when i run using `npm run serve` when i build an apk and run it on my android device the output is messed up.
Does anyone know how to build a table in weex.
And does anyone have any good documentations or tutorials regarding weex.
thanks
[image: SCAN QR code with weex playground app to see output]

Comment: Use div elements instead of table element. ;)

Comment: @PathumSamararathna Already tried it and got same results

Answer (score 0):

It looks like HTML but Weex does not render actual HTML on native. The `<div>`s you write are Weex components that get translated to the target platform.

So while running on a browser may render tables, until Weex has a default `<table>` component, it won't render on native as you expect.

You can create your own component and lay it out using flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, Weex doesn't use HTML but rather has a XML syntax which looks alike. So you need to implement something akin to a  using only `<div>`s. I had to do exacly that, so I might as well post it here.

```
<template>
  <div class="table">
    <div class="row heading">
      <div class="cell headingColumn">Table</div>
      <div class="cell">2</div>
      <div class="cell">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell headingColumn">Row 1</div>
      <div class="cell">2</div>
      <div class="cell">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell headingColumn">Row 2</div>
      <div class="cell">2</div>
      <div class="cell">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<style scoped>
.table {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;

  height: 60px;
}
.cell {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  flex-grow: 1;

  /*width: 100px;*/
  padding: 20px;
}
.heading {
  background-color: grey;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.headingColumn {
  width: 120px;
}
</style>
```

Copy and paste it into dotwe.org and it will work and be rendered as expected in Android & the web.

---

As a side note, if you specify fixed widths (or `min-width`s) for the columns, styling will be much easier. That's why I've specified a `.headingColumn` class and there's a commented `width:100px` value inside `.cell`.

---

BTW, you might need to edit the  and add a  tag inside them with the text content you want.